# Xcode 10 crashes on opening the specific project with unrecognized selector sent to class exception

Tags: xcode, xcode10

Just faced an issue with xCode 10 - it continuously crashes on specific project opening with the following exception:

> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 10B61
>   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[NSColor detailAccentColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff911ce0a8
>   UserInfo: (null)

Weird, but xCode 10 beta was working fine with the same project before xCode update, currently it's just hanging.

Has anyone faced the same issue?
How did you solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved after installing Mac OS Mojave.
It was Mac OS Mojave beta before

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happen as well, solve after update to latest Mac OS Mojave version.

Answer (score 0):

First: Quit Xcode and delete the DerivedData folder you use for your project.

If that doesn't solve it:
Try rolling back to a previous stable commit, such as before any Xcode 10 betas at all. Then open that in Xcode 10 (after deleting your DerivedData directory).  If that works, I'd then start adding back whatever project changes you had done in commits after that one.

And if you don't use Git, well, now you know why you should *always* use Git or another source management system.  Be prepared to rebuild your entire project from scratch (though you can look at your previous project in Xcode 10 beta for reference purposes as you start over on your project).

Comment: thanks for response! installing Mac OS Mojave release instead of Beta helped