# Xcode Error while trying to run/create project

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I'm working on a virtual machine with MacOS 10.14 Mojave (macOS 10.13 High Sierra (64-bit)), and when I run Xcode, it normally display "Welcome to Xcode", but when I try to create project, open existing project or getting started with a playground, it throws an error. I reinstalled whole app and deleted all projects (so I guess derived data is not a problem). I'm not into mac, and my objective is just to run project created in react-native. Here are all informations given by Xcode:
https://pastebin.com/5qtbb72W?fbclid=IwAR0lgvMVJu4E4KYIICdTe5kIpwbg2o_4op5VT_1x5a9Zgo5LkAfKULHD1W4

```
Xcode Version: 10.1 (10B61)
```

Comment: You're listing two different OS versions - which one is it? Looks like someone had the same problem/error and the issue was resolved after upgrading from Mojave Beta to Mojave. (Are you running Mojave beta?) 
Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148239/xcode-10-crashes-on-opening-the-specific-project-with-unrecognized-selector-sent

Comment: In Oracle VM VirtualBox operating system is listed as 10.13 High Sierra, but I'm pretty sure it's 10.14 Mojave. Here is link for the site from I've downloaded it: https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-10-14-mojave-virtualbox-windows/

Comment: What does the version say under About This Mac -> Overview?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmEO4.png

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223484/xcode-10-1-crashes-on-open-due-to-detailaccentcolor-unrecognised#comment93337667_53223484